# Can we set server configuration while doing load testing using Jmeter?

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, load-testing

I have requirements to do the load test on RPC calls(web services) with huge data for example 50,000 users and etc.., So what are the dependencies to vary the results(I mean it varies from server configuration,like that I need to know what the dependencies are)? And can we set the server configuration from Jmeter? Please let me know if there are any options in jmeter to increase the load gradually to meet the maximum limit of that server. What will happen when the load reaches its maximum value?

Comment: I'm not sure what 50,000 users means.  To use JMeter, you need to think in terms of requests (not users) per unit time.

Answer (score 2):

> So What are the dependencies to vary the results(I mean it varies from server configuration,like that i need to know what are the dependencies) ? And can we set the server configuration from the Jmeter.

You set the target URL. JMeter makes a series of network requests to whatever endpoint you specify.

> Please let me know is there any option in jmeter to increase the load gradually to meet the maximum limit of that server.

Yes, you set the "ramp up" for a "thread group".

> what will happen when load reaches to its maximum value ??

Your tests will run to completion.

Sounds like you could benefit from reading the tutorial: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/

I also recommend watching a How-To or two on YouTube (most are 10 minutes long).

Comment: Stepping up thread group can also be used for for increasing the load gradually in a more managed way. It has been designed and used for simulating load as per more real world scenario in a stepped way. You can specify the RampUp time too in that Thread group. Just have a look over the link http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup/  You can hold maximum number of user load for several minutes, before you start deceasing your load to see 'What happens with application when peak load is maintained for few minutes after it is increased.'